# Can I get sheet name from Cell in AppsScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

```
var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var shtinput = Sheet.getSheetByName('INPUT');
var shtdb = Sheet.getSheetByName('Database');
var tgl = shtinput.getRange('D5').getValue();`
```

Can I change 'database' to variable "tgl" ?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `Can I Get sheet name from cell?` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `shtinput = Sheet.getSheetByName('INPUT'); can I change "input" with cell variable?`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: i was edited the question

Comment: i need to change the sheet name to variable cell

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Can I change 'database' to variable "tgl" ?`, is your expected answer `var tgl = shtdb.getSheetName();` instead of `var tgl = shtinput.getRange('D5').getValue();`? I apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected result.

Comment: my expected result is var shtdb = Sheet.getSheetByName( 'D5' ) and then i can select my sheet in D5 cell in droppoint

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `'Database'` with the variable `tgl` like this:

```js
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tgl = ss.getRange('INPUT!D5').getDisplayValue();
  const shtdb = Sheet.getSheetByName(tgl);
```

See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Custom Function

```
function SHEETNAME() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getSheet().getParent().getName();
}
```